# Single wiener process (Brownian Motion)

Tags: python, numpy

The governing equation for the position of a particle is: X(t+dt) = X(t) + ((dt)^0.5)*U

where U is a Normal(0,1) random variable.

I am trying ultimately  to solve for X_0 = X(t=0), X(t=dt), X(t=2dt),...,X(t=Nt)

where N is large and dt is small, however I've started by trying to solve for X_0 first (with Nt=1000 normal random numbers,so I get 1000 different solutions)

I have imported `numpy.random` as `npr`

```
def wiener1(dt=0.1,X0=X(t=0),Nt=1000):
    """ Input variables:
    dt    time step
    X0    intial value, X(t=0) = X0
    Nt    number of time steps 
    """
    X(t+dt)=X(t)+sqrt(dt)*npr.randn(Nt)
    return X0
```

If I type this into my python terminal, I get a an error message for the line
`X(t+dt)=X(t)+sqrt(dt)*npr.randn(Nt): 'can't assign to function call'`

I don't understand this error in this context.

Comment: What is X? How is it defined? If it's a numpy.array you should use `X[t]` and not `X(t)` and where is `t` defined???

Comment: How shall I define them? I'm rather confused, I've spent ages on this and have got nowhere.

Comment: maybe you should start from the start and read a tutorial... that's all very basic stuff.

Comment: Do i define X as a function?

Comment: FYI: http://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.org/items/BrownianMotion.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach doesn't even touch `X0` before returning it, so I'm not quite sure whether my attempt meets your requirement. I'm with @Watten Weckesser concerning reading the scipy-cookbook, but for your approach the solution could be the following:

For the hole temporal evolution

```
def wiener1(dt=0.1,X0=X(t=0),Nt=1000):
    """ Input variables:
    dt    time step
    X0    intial value, X(t=0) = X0
    Nt    number of time steps 
    """
    # create result array
    res = numpy.zeros(Nt)
    # initialize start value
    res[0] = X0
    # calculate and store time series
    for ii in range(1,Nt):
        #         X(t+dt)=X(t)+sqrt(dt)*npr.randn(Nt)
        res[ii] = res[ii-1] + sqrt(dt)*npr.randn(Nt)

    # return time series
    return res
```

In case you are just interested in the final value, you can spare the array memory and do the following:

```
def wiener1(dt=0.1,X0=X(t=0),Nt=1000):
    """ Input variables:
    dt    time step
    X0    intial value, X(t=0) = X0
    Nt    number of time steps 
    """
    # initialize start value
    res = X0
    # calculate and store time series
    for ii in range(1,Nt):
        #         X(t+dt)=X(t)+sqrt(dt)*npr.randn(Nt)
        res += sqrt(dt)*npr.randn(Nt)

    # return final value after t = N*dt
    return res
```

Of course, both approaches need an `import numpy.random as npr`, and the first additionally needs an `import numpy`.

Comment: I wonder if `res[ii] = res[ii-1] + sqrt(dt)*npr.randn(Nt)` should have been `res[ii] = res[ii-1] + sqrt(dt)*npr.randn(1)` in the first case. Similarly, `res += sqrt(dt)*npr.randn(Nt)` should have been `res += sqrt(dt)*npr.randn(1)` in the second case.